# Can we define $\mathbb{C}$ by 'adding' the root to any polynomial not in the reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

In some sense, we define $\mathbb{C}$ by "adding" to $\mathbb{R}$ one of the roots to the equation $x^2+1=0$, which we denote $i$. But my intuition says that the polynomial $x^2+1$ is not special here, and any other polynomial could (in principle) do.

Thus let $p(x)$ be a (real) polynomial of degree $>1$ with $< \text{deg}(p)$ real roots. I make the following claim, which I would appreciate if the community can verify is true or not.

> **Claim:** There exists a unique field structure $K$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(0,1)$ is a root of $p$, *and* $K$ is a field-extension of $\mathbb{R}$, where we identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, $K \cong \mathbb{C}$.

If this claim is not true, are there modifications/"weakenings" we can make to make it true? For instance by forcing $p$ to be quadratic?

A related question I have is, if this claim is true, is it possible to define a new theory of complex analysis on $K$ rather than the usual $\mathbb{C}$? And would this be substantively different from our usual complex analysis (I would suspect not, and it would only make most computations uglier)?

Comment: any real polynomial is factorable in linear and quadratic factors over the reals, so any such non-real root is a root of a quadratic

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think the following is true:

Take a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients, whose roots do not all lie in $\Bbb R$.
Let $a$ be such a root.
Then the field extension ${\Bbb R}(a)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$

Comment: Isn't this essentially the result of Steinitz' following classical paper: https://eudml.org/doc/149323?
(If someone can tell me how to hyperlink urls I'd be grateful. \href and \url don't seem to work)

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation I do not know about the result of Steinitz, but this result is quite easy to prove from the fact that algebraic closures are isomorphic

Answer (score 0):

the polynomial $^2+1$ is special enough to study. it is the **minimal** polynomial whose roots define $i$. and you will see that if you want to construct $\mathbb{C}$ out of the polynomial ring **with two variables** $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$
in reals, the subgroup (ie. the Ideal) that the plynomial above generates will be enough to add as the quotient factor.

For this construction, you shall use the archaic way and begin with defining $\mathbb{C}$ to be the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$